# Improve Mongodb Update Performance

Tags: c#, mongodb

We are trying to update a mongodb document using c# driver which has more than 150 properties using ReplaceOneAsync and found it is taking 90ms to do the same, here is the sample code snippet for the same:

```
collection.ReplaceOneAsync(n => n.key.Equals(key), value, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = false });
```

Could you please let us know if there is any efficient way to do this. Our SLA is 30ms and our application is multi threaded.

Comment: Is key indexed?

Comment: Have you used the [mongodb explain functionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to look into exactly how the query is being processed?

Comment: Yes we have indexed @SJFJ

Comment: You don't update your document, you replace it completely. That make sense if there are a lot of properties, that are changed, or if you don't know, what is changed exactly. If you just want to update a couple of properties, you could use update statement, instead of replace

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Maksim's comment.

Depending on the total number of fields in the document and the number of fields you actually want to update, you might consider using an update instead of replace. The syntax for such an operation might look something like this:

```
var update = Builders<MyMongoDbType>.Update
    .Set(x => x.Name, "Some name")
    .Set(x => x.EmailAddress, "some email")
    .CurrentDate(x => x.DateLastUpdated);

var result = await MyCollection.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.key == "someKey", update);
```